# Most pythonic way of function with no return?

Tags: python, pep8

A I couldn't find anything concerning in the PEP 8. I'm interested in your thoughts about the most pythonic syntax of function which have no return?

Are there any reason to prevent functions without a return line(example 3)?

Example 1:

```
def foo():
   print 'foo'
   return None
```

Example 2:

```
def foo():
   print 'foo'
   pass
```

Example 3:

```
def foo():
   print 'foo'
```

Comment: Example 3 ofcourse!

Comment: You shouldn't use the `pass` statement here. From the doc: "It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action."

Comment: Why the hell would you even use the first two?

Comment: @TC1 Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @TC1 you may require a return statement from a function, that's case 1. Case 2 is when you use pass as a placeholder, then add code to the function and forget to remove the pass statement line.

Comment: @glglgl And simple is better than complex. If it's not supposed to have a return value, just write it that way. The first example implies that there's some dynamic thing going on and that whatever `foo()` constitutes may be used in a place that requires its return value.

Comment: @glglgl In this case is more complex. Actually it's plain wrong, in python at least.

Comment: @TC1 Yes, and iff this is the case, be explicit. IOW, [thg435's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13307243/296974) is kind of perfect.

Comment: @rantanplan Right. In this case, it is "wrong", because explicitness is not needed here. But if I intend to return a value which happens to be `None` in certain cases, I explicitly return `None`.

Comment: @glglgl Yes. That was not the case here however. He gave us 3 examples and the most pythonic was ex-3.

Comment: That's right. In exactly this example, `return None` is bad. But there may be cases (such as in some answers) where a `return None` is to be preferred. My comment at this place was deplaced.

Comment: What about just `return`, by itself, with no arguments? It seems to be equivalent to `return None`, but looks nicer. I often use use it just to make it clear where a function exits, as a kind of visual separator from the function below.

Answer (score 18):

Keep it simple. Example 3 is the most pythonic way.

```
>>> import this

The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

...
Simple is better than complex.
...
```

Comment: But explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: We won't achieve anything by throwing aphorisms that are more relevant to the design of systems than to the syntax of code. Thg435's answer is much better because it contains a reflexion about how to express best what you want your code to mean.

Answer (score 15):

There are two use cases:

- a function that never returns anything (a.k.a "procedure"). You should omit return altogether.
- a function that returns None for some inputs. I personally prefer to put `return None` there, because otherwise it might slightly confuse the reader:

example:

```
 def find_user(name):
     if database.is_ready():
        return database.find_user_by_name(name)
     else:
        return None
```

Technically, you can drop the `else` part, but that would make the function look confusing.

Comment: This is ugly practice right now I speak from reader's position. Just return None without else!

Comment: It is unnecessary from the execution point of view, but it serves to indicate to the reader that this function will return None is the database is not ready by design, and that it's not just something overlooked by the writer.

Comment: @madjar The reader should learn how to read python. The indentation clearly indicates the execution flow.

Answer (score 11):

The [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) has a recommendation on this topic:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either **all** return statements in a function should return an expression, or **none** of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None , and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

Yes:

```
def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return None

def bar(x):
    if x < 0:
        return None
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

No:

```
def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)

def bar(x):
    if x < 0:
        return
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

Comment: Why not def foo(x):
                 if x >= 0:
                     return math.sqrt(x)
. It's really convenient, not place return where it's present by default as well as else/

Comment: These are examples

Answer (score 7):

If you function returns a value, that may be `None` is some case, `return None` is good.

If you function doesn't return a value, but you want to return early, use `return` without any parameter. On the last line, you can omit it.

`pass` does nothing, and is only useful when a statement is needed to avoir a syntax error (in an empty class, for example)

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated Option 3 is by far the best.

Even more of a reason Option 3 is a good idea is that many people are of the opinion that `None` (aka `null` in other languages) should generally never be returned and that you should throw an exception or use the Null Object pattern. While I don't entirely agree with that I think there is some valid point of avoiding using `None` particularly explicitly when it doesn't semantically make sense and is ambiguous.

I'm not saying you should never return `None` but in general I don't think its a good idea.

You can even see this in Python today where `blah['DOESNOTEXIST']` will throw an exception where in Java `map.get("DOESNOTEXIST")` will return `null`.

Comment: *many people are of the opinion* who are those people? every `__init__` returns `None`. It's just how how it supposed to be. It's a perfectly valid and normal return value. also `dict.get('doesntexit')` returns `None` in Python too.

Comment: Many people being FP programmers. Many languages don't have the concept of null. Many people being Tony Hoare the very inventor of null: *I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null reference in 1965. ... But I couldn't resist the temptation to put in a null reference, simply because it was so easy to implement. This has led to innumerable errors, vulnerabilities, and system crashes, which have probably caused a billion dollars of pain and damage in the last forty years.* But is it Pythonic to return `None` sometimes... sure absolutely.

Comment: Seriously ... I got downvoted because I said avoid using null when it doens't make sense! `dict.get('doesntexist')` is a bad a example. 
Did you bind `None` in the map or does it not exist? There are many things in Python that work because of historic reasons and I hate when people say its to keep it simple. Simple is a opinion.